# How to configure AWS classic load balancer to use AWS SSL for both 80 and 8080?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, rtmp, amazon-elb, aws-acm

We are using Nginx-RTMP Streaming and trying to redirect both 80 and 8080 to https. We have tried with redirecting different SSL port in AWS Classic load balancer but its doesn't work.

Nginx RTMP Statistics URL->http://domainname:8080/stats

Please provide solution to use https for both 80 & 8080?

Answer (score 0):

This is our setup for a classic load balancer with redirection to 8080. Replicate it adding the 80 port redirection, and do not forget the SSL certificate.

[image: classic ELB]

Comment: Yes. We have tried above solution already but still https://streaming.example.com:8080/stats is not working.             Is it due to redirection done under application load balancer configured for main domain example.com?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it could be but we would need more info about the web server config. In our case the nginx config has no special setup, just the alias to the streaming.example.com at port 80.

Comment: listen      80;
        listen      8080;
        listen      443 ssl;
        server_name Server-IP "streaming.example.com";

Comment: did you try removing the 443 and 80 listen directive?

Comment: Here i have to use both 80 and 8080. will remove listener port and check it for 8080

Comment: Thanks for your support. Issue has got fixed

Comment: It would be nice to add the solution as an "edit" in the question, in case someone has the same problem :)